# How to Remove FindBugs inspections from code editor

Tags: intellij-idea, findbugs

This may be a simple and silly question, but searches thus far have only turned up how to turn this feature on and run it.

I am using FindBugs-IDEA in IntelliJ 2017. I ran a scan over my code to check see just how bad things were (they're bad). Fine and well, I will work on these later (I swear!) - but I want to remove ALL of the underlining and code inspections from the code editor - but I don't know how to remove them, or disable the findbugs' scan results once it has completed. Any idea?

I don't mind if it's permanent or temporary, I'll rerun the scan when I'm in a position to fix the bugs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems there is a simple answer to this question: Just press the button with the red 'X'. This will make all FindBugs issues go away in the editor windows until you re-run the scan.

[image: FindBugs Clear Button]

The tool window which contains this button may be called up by selecting *View → Tool Windows → FindBugs-IDEA* from the main menu. Hope this helps!

Comment: That's a "I've been working too long today" face palm on my part - that did it, thanks! A complete restart of IntelliJ also did the trick too - but this is a lot better.